# Swiper API loop:true not working with allowSwipeToPrev: false

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Swiper API **loop:true** not working with **allowSwipeToPrev: false**

for example

```
<script>
var swiper = new Swiper('.sales_corner .swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    paginationClickable: false,
    initialSlide: 0,
    allowSwipeToPrev: false,
    loop:true,      
</script>
```

If I use the **loop:true** without **allowSwipeToPrev:false**, the loop will work normally, but if I use the **allowSwipeToPrev:false** option, the loop only be repeated once and then not work.

Why is this happening?
please answer about my question.